# Flutter Android: One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version?

Tags: flutter

**my logo**

[image]

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  static String pagename = '/2';
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}
```

**my flutter code**
[image]